# Converting Timestamp('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') to simple datetime format

Tags: python, excel, datetime, timestamp

When I import data from excel in python, the dates there appear in the Timestamp format i mentioned in the title, which makes it very difficult to match dates(I need to match a few specific dates in the entire list i imported and do some calculations). So, is there a way to convert this into datetime format so that i can apply functions like timedelta etc. (or) is there a way of doing what I need without datetime.
Any help would be extremely helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: do you use pandas to import? If yes, then use the function pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp_Column'])

Comment: What format would you like the imported column.  Text or datetime.date?

Comment: @Alexander , datetime.date would be better since I need to do some date manipulations as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the imported date is a Numpy timestamp, how about:

```
import datetime as dt

df['date_format'] = [ts.astype(dt.datetime).date() for ts in df['imported_date]]
```

Comment: It is a numpy timestamp

Comment: @Shashank See revision

Comment: I am getting this error.AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'astype'

Comment: Seems like a Pandas Timestamp.  Could you please check: type(df['imported_date'].at[0])

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'at'.

Comment: type(df['imported_date'][0][0])

Comment: It says "numpy.ndarray"